# comparison with more than one value in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables.  In the first one there is a column called `id`.  I want to select some of these IDs, and to choose from the other table the rows that have these IDs. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn SQL joins.

```
SELECT SecondTable.*
FROM SecondTable 
INNER JOIN FirstTable ON (FirstTable.ID = SecondTable.ID)
WHERE FirstTable.SomeField = 'Something Else'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link to get you started

[Inner Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Basically for your example you would use something like

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.value, table2.value
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.id
```

Comment: but what if I want to select specific rows from the second table, and then make the join?

Comment: Add a where clause to the above statement, so something like WHERE table.value = 'Test'

Comment: I mean something like that: SELECT * FROM records INNER JOIN params ON records.id=(SELECT * FROM params WHERE name='a').id

Comment: @Sakaka - No need for a subquery. Just add a WHERE clause like David mentioned ie `SELECT records.id, ..etc... 
FROM  records INNER JOIN params ON records.id = params.id
WHERE params.name = 'a'`